# toFixed doesn't work on string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want 1.202 to become 1.20 using toFixed() but how come it didn't worked out in my case?

```
<p>1.202</p>
```

JS

```
$('p').text($('p').toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You not getting the text of the `<p>` tag. Change it to

```
$('p').text(Number($('p').text()).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Why the `new` keyword?

Comment: @Xufox, not strictly necessary (just my preference)

Comment: It may be weird and counterintuitive, though, because new Number creates a number object that is not identical with any number, even if it has the same value, e.g. `new Number('5')!==5`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `toFixed()` is not a function of `jQuery` object:

```js
$('p').text(function() {
  return (+this.innerHTML).toFixed(2); // `+`, parsing `string` to `number`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1.202</p>
<p>3.1456</p>
```